# How can I correct an input_shape error produced when following the "Overfit and underfit" TensorFlow tutorial?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am working through the ["Overfit and underfit" TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit) and have reproduced all steps up to the `tiny_model` using the code they supply.  However, when I run the command

```
size_histories['Tiny'] = compile_and_fit(tiny_model, 'sizes/Tiny')
```

I am served the error, **Invalid input shape for input Tensor("data:0", shape=(28,), dtype=float32). Expected shape (None, 28), but input has incompatible shape (28,)**.  I do not understand why the "expected shape" is (None, 28) when the tutorial and I specify that it should be `input_shape=(FEATURES,)` in the definition of the tiny_model.  (We earlier defined `FEATURES = 28`.)

What am I missing here?  My understanding of model construction in TensorFlow is still shaky, so the answer could be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the tutorial, it seems you maybe forgot to include the lines

```py
validate_ds = validate_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

which are just before [this part](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#demonstrate_overfitting) (scroll a bit up). The important part for your error message is the `.batch()` call, which divides the training (and validation) dataset into batches.

The confusing bit in the beginning is that with `input_shape=(FEATURES,)` one sets the shape for *one sample* for the network (in this step you ignore the `batch_size`), but when you call `model.fit(...)`, it expects *batches* of data. Thats the `(None, features)` shape. It is `(None, features)` and not `(batch_size, features)` because TensorFlow handles the batch size as a variable size (`None` stands for variable size in this context). This is mostly done just for the last batch, which is in most cases smaller than the real batch size.
For example, if you have 40 samples and batch size 16: You have batches of 16, 16, 8 data points, because in the last batch is not enough data to fill it completely to 16.

The error you got indicates unbatched data, so the network gets one sample at a time. But the network in TensorFlow always needs a batch size, even if it is just `1` for one sample.

Edit: To solve the error `ValueError: Arguments target and output must have the same rank (ndim)`: The problem here is that the targets has to be in shape `(batch_size, labels)`. If the targets have only one value (as in this case), the list often gets flattened, and the second `labels` dim is not there. To solve this, do use one of the two solutions:
If your data is in numpy arrays/tensorflow tensors etc, you can use

```py
labels = labels.reshape((-1, 1))  # or similar functions
```

If you already have a `Dataset`, use

```py
ds = ds.map(lambda x,y: (x, tf.expand_dims(y, 0)))
```

This maps the dimension expansion to every element of the dataset.

Comment: I am embarrassed.  This answer is basically correct.  I had renamed the outputs of the above `.batch()` calls to make a before-and-after comparison and neglected to change the names back.

Comment: I have recopied the exact code in the tutorial up to and including the command in my question.  When I run this, I encounter the error, **"ValueError: Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 1)"**  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: See my edit, this should solve it.